# Custom exe completes instantly on WinPE without displaying any output

Tags: c++, winpe, dism

I have a C++ executable (built for x64) that is a command line program to capture some information about the machine it is running on. I am trying to run it in a WinPE environment for the first time, the exe completes almost instantaneously without generating any text on the console or writing to a log file it is supposed to create.

This is what I did:

- Followed instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-create-usb-bootable-drive) to created a bootable WinPE USB flashdrive
- Followed instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-mount-and-customize) to add custom binaries, including the exe, to the image
- Booted a machine into WinPE using the flash drive and executed my exe

The program runs fine on regular Windows, so I know there's nothing obviously wrong with it. I am wondering if there is something peculiar to WinPE or if I could be overlooking something else.

Comment: Just a wild guess: Did you compile with `/MT` (instead of `/MD`), i.e. did you statically link the runtime library?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using wmi to query physical properties. If so, make sure you've included the wmi package in winpe. Also make sure you're building a winpe architecture consistent with the application: 32-bit vs 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue and was able to figure out the problem. The issue is there are some dependencies in the binaries that are not available in WinPE image.

I use [this tool](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) to view the dependencies of the binaries and check the availability of the dependencies in WinPE image (windows\system32<dependency>).

The program should run by copying the missing DLL into WinPE, or editing the build config to remove the dependencies from the binary.